# How to get TS from H264 raw file?

Tags: h.264

How to get TS from H264 raw file by using java and transport it via http?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by a _raw_ H.264 file? Compressed H.264 video without a container and audio?

Comment: yes, i mean h264 stream without container

Comment: Look into [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/).

Comment: @user2031207 when you mention TS, do you mean time stamp or transport stream?

Comment: i mean transport stream, thanks